# Does this function do one thing only?

Tags: design-patterns, php, functions, methods

Is the following method considered to be doing one thing only?

I'm wondering about that since it takes an optional argument.

```
public function findErrors($name = null)
{
    if ($name) {
        return isset($this->errors[$name]) ? $this->errors[$name] : [];
    }

    return $this->errors ?: [];
}
```

If not, would it be better / matter to have it separated like the following:

```
public function findErrors()
{
    return $this->errors ?: [];
}

public function findErrorsOf($name)
{
    return isset($this->errors[$name]) ? $this->errors[$name] : [];
}
```

Comment: What language is that ?

Comment: PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. It's clearly got two independent paths. It would be better to separate them into two (possibly overloaded) functions to better decouple them.

Better yet, I would look to eliminate the name specific behavior unless it's *really* that common. What happens if you want to find errors since Thursday? What about errors that contain the word "Banana"? You shouldn't go back to edit this code every time you have a new search criteria - and you shouldn't have one way to find names and another way to find bananas.

Comment: I think I would keep the name specific behavior. These methods are from a `Validator`. So I would be able to get *all* the validated parameters errors with `findErrors()` or just from a specific parameter only with `findErrorsOf($name)`.